# pagebackref showing an error in article preparation

Tags: errors, hyperref

I am getting an error while using `pagebackref=true`. When I dont use `pagebackref=true`, the program works as expected. This is Central European Journal of Computer Science article. Is there any other alternative for `pagebackref`?

[image: error while using page back ref]

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of your code, please and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably class has already loaded package `hyperref`. LaTeX cannot load a package twice (think of `\newcommand` and friends). Therefore LaTeX skips the loading part of `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage`. It  only checks the trailing optional argument, which requests a minimum package version. And it looks at the options. LaTeX has an understanding of packages options, which can be described as "features". If the options of the later `\usepackage` are already present at the first loading of the package, then LaTeX is satisfied. However, if there is at least one new options, not given before, then LaTeX thinks, the user wants a new "feature", but it cannot load an option independent from the package and it throws the error message.

Workarounds:

- Specifying *all* needed options in the first `\usepackage` (or `\RequirePackage`). The help text of the option clash error message lists them.
- The first call of a packages can be hidden in a class or in another package;
  the option cannot be specified directly. `\PassOptonsToPackage` helps:

  ```
  \PassOptionsToPackage{pagebackref=true}{hyperref}
  \documentclass[CEJCS,PDF]{cej}
  ```

  Then the line `\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}` works without error.
  Also the line can be dropped or reduced to `\usepackage{hyperref}` for the case the class `cej` might forget to load `hyperref` or to make the dependency explicit.
- Some classes (packages) offer special options to pass additional options to packages loaded by the class, e.g. option `hyperref` of class `beamer`.